# global data, static and new

Tags: java

Basic question from somebody coming from structured into object programming... hoping not to be too basic.

I want to have a large array of data that is been shared by different classes inside my application.
What's the best practice to do this?
Is this correct?

```
public class LargeData {
    private static long[] myData;
    private static final int MAX = 100000;

    public LargeData() {
        myData = new long[MAX];
        // ... initialize
    }

    public long getData(int x) {
    // ... do whatever and return a long
    }
}
```

And if this is correct, how is the correct way to access this data from any of my classes? Should I make a

```
LargeData ld = new LargeData();
```

inside every single class that wants to access to myData?

Thank you and sorry for being too easy... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you call

```
LargeData ld = new LargeData();
```

in your code, you will be effectively calling

```
myData = new long[MAX];
```

which is wrong.

What you can do is:

```
public class LargeData {

    private static final int MAX = 100000;
    public static long[] myData = new long[MAX];
}
```

and access it as `LargeData.myData` from anywhere.

Comment: I suppose I should make one "new" at the very beginning?

Comment: Thank you, I think that everyone repeating me the same thing over and over made me understand :)

Answer (score 4):

use a Singleton pattern for this.

Comment: What the purpose of using `Singleton` pattern for holding just array reference?

Comment: Isn't singleton a good practice to perform lazy initialization?

Comment: well, to keep it simple... by using statics you are relying on the classloader to never let go of the class instance (because if he does let go, and the GC kicks in all the data in the static collection is gone). by using a Singleton you can somewhere hold a live reference to your collection and GC will skip it. in that case myData should not be static either. Therefore, Singleton is a good choice.

Comment: +1 in the accepted answer you could easily lose the entire array by someone calling: `LargeData.myData = new long[1]`. Although it would be nice to see an example of how it could be done with Singleton

Answer (score 1):

initialize array immediately. with current implementation you won't be able to use static array until create object of `LargeData`.

Also if class just for holding array prevent its instantiation and extension by making it `final` and constructor as `private`.

```
public final class LargeData {
    public static long[] myData = new long[100000];

    private LargeData() { }
}
```

And get access as `LargeData.myData`

Comment: Sorry. Not sure what I was thinking. Will delete my previous comment. Feeling stupid :/

Comment: In this way I don't need to have any instance of this class, right? I don't need to make any new.

Comment: Thank you, I think that everyone repeating me the same thing over and over made me understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Assigning values to static variables from instance constructors is a bad idea without a null check - if you ever instantiate two objects from this class the second will cause you to lose all data stored in the array (you lose the reference to the old array when the second instantiation overwrites the static reference). With null check it is also a bad idea though, unless you really really really need the data in one instance sort of a "global variable" way. It is best to think of static references as global variables which can be either viewable by all (if they are public) or visible only from the class you define it in (private) or something in between (protected or package protected access). You pretty much want to avoid using them though in almost all cases and use the Singleton pattern instead of static variables inside classes. With the Singleton pattern you use instance variables and non-static getters to get to the data.

However I do not see given the things you wrote why you would need a singleton pattern for this particular problem - you just want to store data in an object and share that object around, right?

You can fix the posted code like this without static keywords and this allows multiple LargeData instances to be alive at once in your application:

```
public class LargeData {
private  long[] myData; // instance variable to store the data
private static final int MAX = 100000; // max length


public LargeData() {
     myData = new long[MAX];
```

}

```
public long[] getData() {
     return myData;
}

}
```

Then you can use the data as:

```
LargeData ld = new LargeData();
long[] = ld.getData();
```

And you can use the reference stored in ld any way you like, you can pass it around your other classes, etc.

A better idea would be to not expose the array, rather create an API through which you use the stored data. For example:

```
public long getLong(int n) { return myData[n]; }
public void setLong(int n, long value) { myData[n] = value; }
```

Now if you don't want to pass around the reference to the LargeData instance stored in ld, you can use a static variable in LargeData to store the reference and a static getter which lets you access it from any other java code. If you need multiple LargeData instances to work with you can create a LargeDataRegistry class that encapsulate a Map where you would store each instantiated LargeData instance.